# Producing events into joined topic at the end of the kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Issue: I am working with a stream of events that involve changes in the user state represented by `Topics.USER_STATE`. My objective is to create notifications about user state change by creating a new record in the `Topics.NEW_NOTIFICATION_TOPIC` when certain requirements are met. However, there is a complication: I must determine whether a notification has already been sent or not.

To address this challenge, I am using another topic called `Topics.NOTIFICATIONS_SENT`. Within this topic, I maintain a record of whether a notification has been dispatched previously or not. Through a left join operation, I though I can figure out if I have already sent notification about that particular change.

I need this functionality because, I can't create duplicates to `Topics.NOTIFICATIONS`, it would end up as multiple notifications for user about the same event over and over again.

```
KTable<String, NotificationsSent> notified = builder.table(Topics.NOTIFICATIONS_SENT, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), NotificationsSent.serdes));

KStream<String, UserState> stream = builder.table(Topics.USER_STATE, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), UserState.serdes))
        .leftJoin(
                notified,
                joinNotified(),
                Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), UserState.serdes)
        .filter(UserState::needToNotify)
        .toStream()

stream.map(...).to(Topics.NOTIFICATIONS_SENT)
stream.map(...).to(Topics.NOTIFICATIONS)
```

However, my initial assumptions were incorrect, and it appears that topology above doesn't work. During testing, I encountered difficulties as I am unable to utilize the same topic for both input and output within the `TopologyTestDriver`. Furthermore, when attempting to execute the code in a testing environment, I find myself caught in a loop of errors after consuming the first record.

How right topology for such use case would look like?

I'm considering the possibility of using a `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore` and a global table for the `NOTIFICATIONS_SENT` topic. Instead of performing a left join operation, I could potentially determine whether a notification has already been sent by mapping and searching for the corresponding record in that store, but I'm not sure if its great idea or just some kind of a "hack workaround" - example:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Key, NotificationsSent> notificationsSentStore;

KStream<String, UserState> stream = builder.stream(Topics.USER_STATE, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), UserState.serdes))
        .map((k,v) -> v.setNotificationsSent(notificationsSentStore.get(k)))
        .filter(UserState::needToNotify)


stream.map(...).to(Topics.NOTIFICATIONS_SENT)
stream.map(...).to(Topics.NOTIFICATIONS)
```